# How to translate different types of UML associaions in Java?

Tags: java, uml

These are bidirecctionals associations i want to translate in JAVA.

A(n)----(m)B

A(1)----(n)B

A(1)----(1)B

How to do it? Down ther is what i'm trying to do but it seems like it is not good. Somebody can correct it please?

***************************** 1…1 association ***************

```
Public final class A{
  Private B objB;
  public getobjB (){}
  public setobjB (){}
}

Public final class B{
  Private A objA;
  public getobjA (){}
  public setobjA (){}
}
```

## Remark

this code above runs the risk to turn in loop how to avoid it Please?

******************** 1…n association ************************************

```
public final class A{
  private ArrayList objB = new ArrayList() ;
  public getobjB (){}
  public setobjB (){}
}

public final class B{
  private A objA;
  public getobjA (){}
  public setobjA (){}
}
```

## Remark

this code above runs the risk to turn in loop how to avoid it Please?

******************************* n…m association ************************

```
Public final class A{
}

Public final class B{
}

Public final class A_B{

 Private A objA;
 Private B objB;

 public getobjA (){}
 public getobjA (){}                    
}
```

## Remark

the code  runs the risk to turn in loop how to solve it please? And it seems like it is not correct?

**To Add something on my complain, That is my really problem**

> the software is running the risk to turn in a loop, is it normal?
>
> Because I could have this:
>
> A a = new A(); B b = a.objB; ==> here you should either turn the
>   property objB to be  public or protected. If you decides to let it as
>   private,  you therefore should put a getter and setter method
>
> Now having my b, I could have an access to objA like this b.objA
>
> At this stage I have the right to access objB like this: b.objA.objB
>
> At this stage I have the right to access objA like this:
>   b.objA.objB.objA
>
> etc...
>
> So as you are seing we are running the risk to turn in loop. That is
>   to say:
>
> Toto pulls Nama. Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama. Nama pulls Toto.
>   Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto.  Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto.
>   Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. 
>   Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto
>   pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto.  Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto
>   pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto.  Toto
>   pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto
>   pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto pulls Nama.Nama pulls Toto. Toto
>   pulls Nama.

Answer (score 1):

Actually most of the code looks fine to me. I tried and none threw stack overflow.

I think you should consider looking at EER to OODB mapping, as most of the concepts are pretty similar. Here is how to map binary relationships.

> If a binary relationship is represented by a reference in only one direction, declare the reference to be an attribute in referencing class whose type is the referenced class name. Depending on the cardinality ratio of the binary relationship, the relationship properties or reference attributes may be single-valued or collection types. They will be single-valued for binary relationships in the 1:1 or N:1 directions; they are collection types (set-valued or list-valued) for relationships in the 1:n or M:N direction. If relationship attributes exist, a tuple (Class) constructor can be used to create a structure of theform , which may be included instead of the reference attriute.

Same is pretty much true for bi-directional mapping. You just include referenced class in both referencing class.

However, for m-n relationship, as mentioned above it is OK to declare the reference to be an attribute in the referencing class, as relationship doesn't have any attribute.

```
class A {
    ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

    public ArrayList<B> getbList() {
        return bList;
    }

    public void setbList(ArrayList<B> bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }
}

class B {
    ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();

    public void setaList(ArrayList<A> aList) {
        this.aList = aList;
    }

    public ArrayList<A> getaList() {
        return aList;
    }
}
```

I see you are confused where variables are declared and where objects are created. Here is helpful program to help you understand.

```
class A {
    B b; //no new object is created

    public B getB() {
        return b;//no new object is created
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b; //no new object is created
    }
}

class B {
    A a; //no new object is created

    public A getA() {
        return a; //no new object is created
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a; //no new object is created
    }
}

public class OneToMany {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); //new object is created
        B b = new B(); //new object is created
        a.setB(b);
        b.setA(a);
        //getting b from a
        B b2 = a.getB(); //no new object is created
        //getting a from b
        A a2 = b.getA(); //no new object is created
        //getting b from b->a
        b2 = a2.getB(); // showing b->a->b (bi-directional) relation is still valid

    }
}
```

Looping will occur when you have something like following.

```
class A {
    B b; //no new object is created

    public A() {
        b = new B(); //new B is created which in turn will create new A and so on
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;//no new object is created
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b; //no new object is created
    }
}

class B {
    A a; //no new object is created

    public B() {
        a = new A(); //new A is created which in turn will create new B and so on
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a; //no new object is created
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a; //no new object is created
    }
}

public class OneToMany {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); //new object is created
        B b = new B(); //new object is created
        a.setB(b);
        b.setA(a);
        //getting b from a
        B b2 = a.getB(); //no new object is created
        //getting a from b
        A a2 = b.getA(); //no new object is created
        //getting b from b->a
        b2 = a2.getB(); // showing b->a->b (bi-directional) relation is still valid

    }
}
```

In above program when you call A a= new A() it will call new B() from it's constructor, which will again call new A() from it's constructor and so on.

Please lookup variable instantiation and declaration in java for further information.

Comment: thank you very much! please i wish to know if it is correct to have a loop because  we can have thisfrom the object A you can get Object B which can return again t Object A etc.

Comment: There isn't really any loop. Take your one-to-one relationship for example, as long as you don't call setter of the another object inside setter of caller object, there is no loop. Like when you call objA.setB(objB); that is all it is going to execute. If you don't have something like objB.setA(this) inside setB, there isn't going to be any loop. They aren't storing objects, they are just referencing them.

Comment: here you are using the set fonction what about the get function?

Comment: please have a look on what i add on my recent post because i added something up there, you will see what i'm talking about

Comment: Having right to access objects in the way mentioned above doesn't turns it into loop. 
b.objA will return instance of objA to the user. Now at this point it is up to the user to decide to call or not to call b.objA.objB. Program itself will not loop.

Comment: I think your misconception is that b stores a which in turns stores b, like b{a{b{...}}} and so on. But what actually happens is there is two separate instance of b and a, and b doesn't stores a, it just stores reference to a, and same thing other way around. So there will be just two objects a and b and they will have reference to each other like b->a and a->b.

Comment: How to put a guard preventive please?

Comment: a doesn't instantiates b itself, ever (unless you are calling new B() inside constructor or field declaration of class A). (Non-Primitive) Objects in java are only created when you use new keyword. Look at answer above, I have added new codes to help you understand.

Comment: Thank You very much for the TIPS! It become clear for me now,!